# Share instance inside local project with different modules

Tags: go

My project strucutred like following

```
myproj
   src
      server
         main.go
      helpres
          helper1.go
          helpr2.go
       utils
          utils1.go
          utils2.go
```

This is the code in the main.go function

```
import “myproj/utils”
import “myproj/helpers”

var log obj    *obj



func init() {
    log = initLog()
    util.passLog(log)
    helper.passLog(log)
    //And then helper and util can use it ...is it the right way to do it ? 
}

func main(){

    log.write()

}
```

Now I was able to use obj1 inside the `server -> main.go`, 
but I want to use the same instance also in `helper1.go` and `utils2.go`
instead create the new one on each module,(later on I call to some functiona from `helper` and `util` inside the `server->main.go`)
How should I do it in golfing?

Comment: Export it. Then use it. Beware of import cycles. Restructure your code and get rid of utils and helpers.

Comment: @Volker, what do you mean export it, could you provide example ? and why refactored ?

Comment: @Volker - I saw that there is init method should I use it for e.g. in util and helprs method to get the object ?

Comment: "Export" in the sense of export the variable, i.e. capitalize its name. Please take the Tour of Go or some other introductionary material for such language basics. Having utils and helpers in separate packages is strange in go. Take a look at how others do such stuff, you'll find lots on the internet.

Comment: @Volker - You write -"separate packages is strange in go.", why , I dont find any reference or best practise where I should put util / helper and other project module related stuff ....

Comment: @volker - https://golang.org/doc/code.html this is talking about helpr like , modules

Comment: @Volker - look at the `stringutil/` so I really dont understand what is wrong in my structure , util and helprs is just example ...I've only one util package not helprs ...so please let me know how should I structure it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing objects between modules isn't good aproach. In your example you are trying to initialize Logger. Look at implementation of GO built-in package [log](https://golang.org/src/log/log.go). Rather provide Api for rest of your modules.

But general approach would be something like this:

```
// Assume this is your logging tools package "internal/tools/logging"
package logging

// First you create local object reference in your logger source file:
var logger = NewLoggerInstance()

// Then you provide global api to use this local reference
func Configure(c Myconfig) { std = NewSpecialInstanceFromConfig(c) }

// Then you can provide actual functionality for other modules as part of Api
func Debug(args ...interface{}) {
   std.Debug(args...) // this will cal method of your internal logger reference stored in variable std
}

// Then other modules just import your package
import <PREFIX>/internal/tools/logging

// And use it like this
c := LoadConfigFromEnvironment()
logging.Configure(c)

logging.Debug("Debug log")
logging.Info("something else")
```

And absolutely take a look at this project [template](https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout).

EDIT:

Example of `Configure()` method.

```
package logging
// lets assume we have package config included, it contains a struct of our application config
func Configure(c config.Config){ 
   // new logger instance
   l := NewLoggerInstance()

   // check value from config
   if c.GetJsonLogFormat() {
       l.SetFormatter(JsonFormater{})
   }

   // some other settings
   l.SetSomething(c.GetSomething())
   // set global package variable
   logger = l
}
```

Loading config from environment can [this](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig) do for you.

Comment: Thanks 1+ , can you please provide example how to implement the `configure`  and especially `LoadConfigFromEnvironment()` , not sure that I fully understand how to do it and example in my context will help... thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Sharing objects between packages is not recommended because it will very likely get messy when things goes wrong. Debugging and finding out where `obj` was called from or mutated will become difficult. Instead, try to pass the `obj` as a parameter to `helper1` and `utils2`.

If you really really do want to share the object, change the name to start with a capital letter, `Obj`. This way the variable is exported from your package and can be used from elsewhere. Note that this will expose `Obj` to everyone who wants to grab it and (mis)use it.

Edit: 
Pass the `obj` to a function in helper:

```
helper.doSomethingHelpfulWith(obj)
```

Comment: Thanks, can you provide example how it's recommended to share it in golang ? I refer to "Instead, try to pass the obj as a parameter to helper1 and utils2."

Comment: thanks, so before I call to the helper 'helper.doSomethingNotHelpful' I need to call to' helper.doSomethingtHelpful`

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment.

Comment: Lets say I want to pass logger which should use inside all the sub package and this logger is init inside the server/main file ,should I init the method of utils inside the init and pass it ? since this code called later on ? ,I'll update my question in a min

Comment: Done I update the question, can you please see the `init` function should I pass the object as I write? I init the logger and pass it to the other modules since they should use this logger and not native logger for example ...

Comment: Depends on your use-case. But If it is only a logger I would not worry about the extra overhead in instantiating it in both main and helper. If it is crucial to use the same object, pass the log as a parameter or Capitalize it to export it. Have a look at https://tour.golang.org/basics/3 for a simple example of exporting stuff from your package.